# Ways to refer to path of folder with reference to existing folder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to point to location of certain folder using current folder as a reference.

I would like to do something neat like this in python. It looks simple and readable.

```
directory_1 = "../data"
directory_2 = "../../data2"  # refer to parent folder
```

I am using python v3.6

EDIT: I made a mistake for `directory_1`. It is easy to get it in python by using `directory_1 = "./data"`. One dot, not 2 dots.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Pretty much every OS python runs on will understand those paths as is.

Comment: I could not get it to work in Windows 10. I had to use `os.getcwd()` instead.

Comment: Why did you have to use it? Show a minimal reproducible example where that would be necessary please.

Comment: IIRC Windows pathing uses backslashes.

Comment: os.getcwd() can work for current folder. There is no neat way to get parent folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

directory_1 = Path("../data").resolve()
directory_2 = Path("../../data2").resolve()
```

Unix:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("../data").resolve()
>>> p
PosixPath('/Users/username/foo')
```

Windows:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("../data").resolve()
>>> p
WindowsPath('C:\\Users\username\foo')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Why the extra layer? +1 for introducing a valuable tool though.